# LiipImagineBundle: Redirection to login instead of showing image

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, liipimaginebundle

I habe the following problem: if an image isn't in the cache, liip imagine redirects to the fosuserbundle/login page. I just can't find wrong configuration...

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
default:
web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    list_item:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            relative_resize: { widen: 164 }`

_liip_imagine: prefix: /images/rs/ resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Liip routes are under your firewall. Thus it forces the user to authenticate.

Try adding this to your `security.yml` (*before* your current firewall):

```
firewalls:
    images:
        pattern:  ^/images/
        security: false
    login:
        # your firewall
```